# Parse HTML that show up after a GET method C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ajax, get

I have a website that use Ajax

When you open up the website, no information show up untill you click a button. The button actually do some GET method to server, and received response, and caculate it, and show up in website (update the HTML sources).

My question is how to parse the HTML source AFTER that caculations? The code of caculation is in JavaScript. and the address is exactly the same as before caculation.

First, i try to use the response data of GET method directly. No luck. The response data is very complicated and i don't even know how it could be caculated

Second, i try to read the JavaScript code to understand how they caculate the data. No luck. I see that they not do anything with data at all. But the result show in HTML is very different from the response data of GET method.

So, how can I get the exact result show up in HTML. I'm use C# for my code. Thanks

I'm try to add details in comment, and type Enter. Sorry for that

Details

This is what show up in Website: [Image1](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g335/cuoilennaocacban1/asking/28-08-201212-26-36PM.png)

First point: 10.740425272880508,106.6190201527238

2nd: 10.743269525582264,106.62160002774681

3rd: 10.74487172053895,106.62348830289329

...

last: 10.77587253871842,106.70619763111029

This is what i get from respose data:

106.61837000000001,10.741180000000002

106.62066000000002,10.7431

(2 point only)

[Image2](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g335/cuoilennaocacban1/asking/28-08-201212-28-04PM.png)

Also, there is another response data in Json format: Link in comment
It's contain number, name, address and 2-not-understanding float

I will post the JavaScript code later. Some trouble in the box.com

Comment: What do you mean by calculate? Could you post this javascript code and maybe an example of the response you get from this ajax request?

Comment: Are you sure that what comes back *even is* html? I would expect any AJAX to be returning AJAX. Also: if it (google maps) isn't your app, why are you trying to parse the result?

Comment: The map is not what i want to get. I want to get the coordinate of the point in that map. They store them in response data. But i can use the response data directly because it seem to be different with the result show on map. I just add some more details to my question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure it out how. I will post the answer after 8-hours limit of StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I know how they caculate the data.

The response data which is contain coordinates is used for direction. It's line 2 point to make a direction, and it's not base on the location of the point i want

Infact, 2-not-understanding float is the exact location. It's not `latitude` and `longitute`. It's use another system call `Universal Transver Mercator`. The map of the earth is flat out to a rectangle, and this system divide that rectangle to many row and column. All I have to do is convert it to `latitude` and `longitude` (which is much more popular). The `UTM` system is still used in some country in the world, and I'm pretty sure NOT my country.

The `JavaScript` code is used for converting is hidden in a very deep level of folder. I use `Google Chrome` to dig it out. And the name of converting method is `not-for-human-reading`, it's a string of random character.

So my problem is now solved. But my question still remain, it's fun i though. How can we parse `HTML` that updated after a `GET` or `POST` method withoud response data? If we can, I will mark this question as answered.